# Python: How to Completely delete Linked List?

Tags: python, linked-list

Lets say that I have such class definition for `Node`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Also I have `head` variable which points to the beginning of linked list.

Is it enough to set `head = None` to completely delete linked list? I suppose gc should do it's work?

I compare it to `c/c++` where you should still iterate over whole list and free every element.

Comment: python uses reference counting ... if head is assigned to the lead node, and then head is reasigned to something else ... the ref-count for the lead node decreases by one ... as long as the ref-count is zero the garbage collector will garbage collect it ... if you are this worried about internal memory management python may not be the right tool for you ... (it tends to do the right thing ... but the internals are often implementation specific)

Comment: @JoranBeasley If the ref count for lead node is 0 than it will be garbage collected and all other linked nodes will be collected by chain?

Comment: as long as the child nodes dont point back to the parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you don't even need to do anything. When the lifetime of the `head` variable ends, if you don't have any other references to the list, the list will become unreachable and eligible for collection automatically. On CPython, it'll usually get collected immediately, but you shouldn't rely on that.

If you want to make the list eligible for collection before the `head` variable's lifetime ends, setting `head = None` would work, as would `del head`. (Note that `del` means "unset this variable", not "delete this object".)

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleteAll(self):
    temp = self.head
    if temp is None:
        print("\n Not possible to delete empty list")
    while temp:
        self.head = temp.get_next()
        temp = None
        temp = self.head
```

Comment: Try to accompany your code with some explanation of *why* and *how* it solves the problem, and in this case, why is it at all necessary